# Org-export to lisp comments

Tags: org-mode, org-export

I like using org-mode in my packages' Readme files, but I also like
writing instructions under the `;;; Commentary:` header that goes in
the source file.

Whenever I change some part of the documentation, the best way I've
found to keep those in sync is to:

1. Edit the org file first.
2. Export to a plain text utf-8 buffer, with the body-only option (`C-c e C-b t U`).
3. Add `;;` at the start of each line.
4. Copy that over to the package file.

**Q:** How can I best automate this?

I can write the necessary elisp for adding `;;` and copying to the
kill-ring, but I'm not familiar enough with the org-export machinery
to know what's The Right Way to do an automated export using a
specific recipe.

---

Bonus points if there's a command I can invoke from a `.el` file which
automatically finds a `Readme.org`, does the whole export, and uses it
to replace the file's `;;; Commentary:`.

Comment: [`el2markdown`](https://github.com/Lindydancer/el2markdown) <- Related as it syncs the readme's from .el Commentaries, but in markdown format. May be then run a batch job to convert to org? Or use that as a basis to write an "el2org" package? :)

Comment: [`poporg`](https://github.com/pinard/poporg) <- Also related. Use `poporg` to edit comments in any major-mode in an `org-mode` buffer. The only extra step would be to save that "popped out org buffer" as an org readme file.

Comment: @kaushalmodi Thanks. I'll have a look at these. Specially poporg.

Comment: `poporg` is priceless.. I must be probably using it once everyday to do stuff like [this](https://github.com/kaushalmodi/.emacs.d/blob/5f3c3a51eacc7bbdc143acc4633f102906fa907f/setup-files/setup-calc.el#L82-L99) without leaving the `.el` files.

Comment: @Malabarba - Would it be useful to use the literate programming features, i.e. noweb & tangle, of org-mode to keep `.el` and `Readme.org` in sync?